# vue.js making a data property = to the return value of a method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, computed-properties

So im trying to assign this.clean = this.cleaner.

The results prop is an array of 20 objects that I want to filter. I want an array of objects that only have a valid poster_path value and to remove the ones that do not meet that requirement. Hence the .filter().

```
  props: ['results'],
  data() {
    return {
      clean: []
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.clean = this.cleaner
  },
  methods: {
    cleaner() {
      return this.results.filter(o => o.poster_path !== null)
    }
  }
```

Problem is using my vue devtool Vue doesnt seem to be saving the this.cleaner value.
I get `{"_custom":{"type":"function","display":"<span>ƒ</span> bound cleaner()"}}` for the value of this.clean.

If I try to use a computed value I keep getting "(error during evaluation)" as the value of this.clean.

If i try `this.clean = this.cleaner()` it just saves an empty array.

Answer (score 1):

Try this snippet. I think your code can be simplified down to this:

```js
const mockData = [
  {
    name: 'abc',
    poster_path: 1
  },
  {
    name: 'def',
    poster_path: null
  }
]
Vue.component('foo', {
  props: ['results'],
  template: '<ul><li v-for="c in clean" :key="index">{{c.name}}</li></ul>',
  computed: {
    clean: function() {
      return this.results ?this.results.filter(o => o.poster_path !== null) : [];
    }
  }
})
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return { results: mockData }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  Foo component: <foo :results="results"/>
</div>
```

Comment: This filtered data will be used in a v-for of a child component. I need to filter the prop and then assign the result as a data variable so i can "v-for in"

Comment: @CiaranO'Riordan see example

Comment: @CiaranO'Riordan Welcome to SO, by the way. When you get a chance, please let me know if this answers your question and mark the answer as accepted, if so.

Comment: thank you alex! your way is definatly cleaner. Think ive narrowed down the issue to be with the filter. Using your code example im getting a type error: o is null. My data in the results prop is exactly like your mockdata so i dont know why it is erroring. Thanks for helping btw!

Comment: @CiaranO'Riordan did you try running the new code snippet?

Comment: oh wow ive figured it out. The data in the results prop was from an api. For some reason the first object in the array was just a null object so the filter was erroring because it could not find o.poster_path. Thanks for your help though. Atleast my code is cleaner !

Answer (score 1):

just assign the functionality of the funcion like this

```
props: ['results'],
data() {
  return {
   clean: []
  }
},
mounted() {
  this.clean = this.results.filter(o => o.poster_path !== null)
}
```

Comment: still leaves me with this.clean being an empty array. Even tried making the filter conditional something definatly true and still an empty array

Answer (score 1):

```
props: ['results'],
data() {
  return {
    clean: this.results.filter(o => o.poster_path !== null)
  }
},
```

Please try it.
You can directly import props to the component data.